# how to find minimumof heap size required for project

Tags: java, spring, struts2, heap-memory, project

I am developing a web based application in *struts2*,*spring* & *hibernate*. 
I would like to know what should be the heap size for this application(& how to determine) for successful working with large number of users(thousands to millions).

Can I user same server(with same heap size) to deploy more than one application with above criteria.

Any server which may fullfill this criteria.

Comment: A million *concurrent* users? Good luck with that on a single machine.

Comment: I dont have any idea about this. but could you suggest whar should be the heap size.

Answer (score 1):

You should not think of a single machine with millions of users. It would be so called 'vertical scaling' which is pricey and also dangerous - if the machine fails, your entire application would become not available. And to add to that, you would most likely hit a well known 10KC problem - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C10k_problem.

Instead you should think of horizontal scaling and lots of caches (like Varnish etc.)

Just to give you a few links: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalability, [Difference between scaling horizontally and vertically for databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11707879/difference-between-scaling-horizontally-and-vertically-for-databases).

It all depends on the type of application you have to write, types of requests, number of requests per second, how many of such requests would read/write to database, how stall data can be returned to the user and MANY more.

Comment: Any more basic things to know

Comment: @xrcwrn There's a ton of stuff to know-but it's not really appropriate for SO. Maybe ServerFault, but in general, consider just researching scalability in whatever domain you're working with, like web, databases, etc.

Comment: You have basically given NO criteria at all considering amount of concurrent users you need to handle - so yes - my answer was a bit vague, but so was the question.

Comment: @R4J,@Dave Newton Ok just tell me how to find minimum heap size.

Comment: @xrcwrn Noone would be able to GUESS such a number if you don't provide more details on a problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: @R4J Ok What details should I provide