# Will there be issue if there is multiple database access by different users?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am currently developing a PHP website and since the website will be used by many people, I just want to know if there will be a problem if there is multiple database access at the same time from those different users, and if so how to go about it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: That depends on your database, your configuration, your setup and alot more factors. Please try to extend your question with some more information.

Comment: Please use a more descriptive question title.

Comment: You are actually asking about how do computers work. This is pretty wide topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SIMPLE ANSWER:** As long as your code is well designed, No.

**Elaborating:** In a MySQL server, databases are made to work very efficiently and to handle a large set of tasks. Among these tasks include the constant querying of tables inside separate databases, among which include statements that `SELECT` data, `UPDATE` data, `INSERT` rows, `DELETE` rows, etc.

There are some corner cases that can happen however. Imagine if two people are registering on your website for the first time, and both of them want to register the username **Awesomesauce**. Programmers often code algorithms that first check if the current username exists, and if it doesn't, `INSERT` a new row in the `users` table with the new username and all the other relevant info (password, address, etc). If both users were to click the Register button at the same time, and if your code was badly designed, what could happen is two rows could be created with the same username, in which case you would have a problem.

Luckily, MySQL as features to prevent such corner cases. A `UNIQUE INDEX` could be implemented on the `username` column, hence forcing the database not to accept one of the two users who tried to register the name at the exact time.

All in all, if your code is well designed, you shouldn't have a problem.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on how much traffic, how large your site's database is and a host of other factors.

But for starters, i'ld say there's really nothing to worry about.

I think you should go with MySQL since you are just starting out with php, but you can pretty much use whatever you want with PHP's PDO http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php. There is a lot of online support for mysql with php, so I would start there.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest make multiple tables in same db rather than multiple db. Though there won't be any problem even if there are multiple db access at same time.

Refer following link to know how its done:-
[How do you connect to multiple MySQL databases on a single webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274892/how-do-you-connect-to-multiple-mysql-databases-on-a-single-webpage)

Answer (score 0):

While your question is way too broad, if you want horizontal scaling (adding more servers) look at a PHP/NoSQL solution. Otherwise, something like PHP/MySQL will be fine.

A bit of reading for you here: [Difference between scaling horizontally and vertically for databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11707879/difference-between-scaling-horizontally-and-vertically-for-databases)