# horizontal scaling and vertical scaling naming convention

Tags: scale, scalability, distributed-computing

I know horizontal scaling refers to adding more instances, vertical scaling refers to improving capability of single instance.

My question is why naming this way?  why not the other way around ?  Is there some common in horizontal and more instances ? or is it just naming convention

Comment: I think this answer is related http://stackoverflow.com/a/11715598/1638814

Comment: @nvartolomei thank you very much. I came up with a way which is x axis is for instances number, and y axis is for single instance power