# Create big web app like Facebook

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, database

now i have asp.net mvc app with mysql db . i have million records with hug numbers of users . so one server can't work fine how can i run my app in many servers and have a good performance like facebook

Comment: It's difficult to understand what you are asking. I would recommend that you [edit] the question, using proper punctuation and including specific, relevant details to clarify what you mean. See [ask].

Comment: this is absolutely the worst question I have seen today.  Rework it or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to read about Load Balancing. There multiple ways to do load balancing and there different definitions as well. One is the following.

1. Vertical Load Balancing - you scale by adding more machines into
   your pool of resources
2. Horizontal Load Balancing - You scale by
   adding more power (CPU, RAM) to an existing machine.

Credits : [Difference between scaling horizontally and vertically for databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11707879/difference-between-scaling-horizontally-and-vertically-for-databases)

You can get an understanding on practical methods to do these by articles like the following.

- https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/5-common-server-setups-for-your-web-application
- https://www.nginx.com/resources/glossary/load-balancing/
- https://dzone.com/articles/load-balance-your-web-applicat